# Why the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}_p/\mathbb Q_p)$ on $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$ restricts to $\overline{\mathbb Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

Let $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb C$ and chose an algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$ for $\mathbb Q_p$. The embedding $\mathbb Q \hookrightarrow \mathbb Q_p$ extends to an embedding $\overline{\mathbb Q} \to \overline{\mathbb Q}_p$ such that
$$
  \begin{array}{rcl}
      \overline{\mathbb Q} & \longrightarrow & \overline{\mathbb Q}_p \\
      \uparrow & & \uparrow\\
      \mathbb Q & \longrightarrow & \mathbb Q_p
  \end{array}
$$
Milne in his notes on Elliptic curves writes that  $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}_p/\mathbb Q_p)$ acts on $\overline{\mathbb Q}$, in other words, the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}_p/\mathbb Q_p)$ on $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$ restricts to an action on $\overline{\mathbb Q}$, i.e. for any $x \in \overline{\mathbb Q}$, $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}_p/\mathbb Q_p)$ we have $\sigma(x) \in \overline{\mathbb Q}$. But why this is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $f(x)=0$ implies $f(\sigma x)=0$ when $f$ has coefficients in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I see (This area is new for me, so sorry for the stupid question).